# Media Files and Static files not Displaying and working in Django

Tags: django, django-urls, django-staticfiles, django-media

when deployed server then static files not working and media files not diplaying. 404 error

here is the urls.py

```
from django.views.static import serve
import django
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path ('' , include('home.urls'))
]  +  static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/usr/local/lsws/Example/html/demo/static'

"""STATICFILES_DIRS=(
    BASE_DIR / "static",
   
)"""

MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/usr/local/lsws/Example/html/demo/static/media'

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads'
```

Comment: `when deployed` you mean _on prod_? with debug=false?

Comment: yes on prod and debug=True

Comment: Verify that on prod it's the same folder and the user running webserver has access to this folder. Consider using BASE_DIR instead of absolute paths. Also you might prefer to store projects files not inside user private home folder and store them somewhere /var/opt or whatever. If you had media files locally before deployment then they must be copied to prod manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that on prod it's the same folder and the user running webserver has access to this folder. Consider using BASE_DIR instead of absolute paths. Also you might prefer to store projects files not inside user private home folder and store them somewhere /var/opt or whatever. If you had media files locally before deployment then they must be copied to prod manually. –
Thank you @Ivan-Starostin